# Swift Method - Multiple Parameters "extra argument in call" Error

Tags: swift, methods, cloudkit

I am trying to utilise methods in my code.

I have created a new swift file named:
ClipManager.swift

Which has my Save Function:

```
class ClipManager{
func SaveMethod(publicDatabase: CKDatabase, myRecord:CKRecord ) -> CKRecord  
{

    publicDatabase.saveRecord(myRecord, completionHandler:
        ({returnRecord, error in
            if let err = error {
                self.notifyUser("Save Error", message:
                    err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.notifyUser("Success",
                        message: "Record saved successfully")
                }

                ///self.currentRecord = myRecord
            }
        }))
/// return myRecord
}
}
```

I am trying to call it from my viewcontroller.swift file:

```
let currentRecord = ClipManager.SaveMethod(publicDatabase, myRecord)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> extra argument in call

Comment: Aren't static methods in Swift preceded by `class func`?

Comment: Be aware that `saveRecord:completionHandler` works asynchronously. The completion handler is called much later after the method has finished. It is impossible to return `returnRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first issue is that `SaveMethod` is an instance method .i.e should be called on an instance and not the class. The compiler is telling you there is an extra argument because when you call an instance method on the class of this instance it is expecting you to provide the instance which the method should bind to. For example:

```
let myClipManager = ClipManager()
let mySaveMethod = ClipManager.SaveMethod(myClipManager)
let currentRecord = mySaveMethod(publicDB, myRecord: myRecord)
```

this is equivalent to the following

```
let myClipManager = ClipManager()
let currentRecord = myClipManager.SaveMethod(publicDB, myRecord: myRecord)
```

the second approach is easier to understand though, or you can just declare the SaveMethod as class func which can be called directly on the class.

Concerning your question about why do you need to declare the name of the second parameter but not the first, in Swift by convention the name of the first parameter is not required as it should be deduced from the method name itself. For example:

```
func saveRecord(record: CKRecord, inDatabase: CKDatabase){}
// call the method
saveRecord(myRecord, inDatabase: myDatabase)
```

here the first parameter name `record` can be omitted as it is deduced from the method name `saveRecord` which clearly takes a record and saves it. Nevertheless you can force the first parameter name to be required. For example:

```
func saveRecord(record record: CKRecord, inDatabase: CKDatabase){}
// the method should be called like this
saveRecord(record: myRecord, inDatabase: myDatabase)
```

moreover you can specify 2 names for the same parameter, the first to be used when called and the second to be used inside the function body. For example:

```
func saveRecord(record aRecord: CKRecord, inDatabase db: CKDatabase) {
   // to use the passed record you should use the aRecord variable
   // to use the passed database you should use the db variable
   save(aRecord, db)
}
// but the method should be called in the following way
saveRecord(record: myRecord, inDatabase: myDatabase)
```

Last but not least, you can omit the necessity of adding a name for any parameter using the following:

```
func saveRecord(record: CKRecord, _ db: CKDatabase) {}
// call the method
saveRecord(myRecord, myDatabase) // you don't have to name the second parameter because of the _ before its name
```

So when you precede the name of a parameter with an `_` this means that the caller can omit the name of this parameter when calling the method and by default in Swift the first parameter name is omitted without the need of preceding its name with an `_`

Comment: Thank you for the very through answer. I'll change to an instance method now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong here:

- you are trying to call a non-class method statically
- You are missing the `myRecord:` in the call:

To get it to work you have to write the function definition in the following way

```
class func SaveMethod(publicDatabase: CKDatabase, myRecord:CKRecord ) -> CKRecord {
    ...
}
```

and the call has to look something like

```
let currentRecord = ClipManager.SaveMethod(publicDatabase, myRecord: myRecord)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Two quesions:

If I am to call it a an instance, how would this be done, by making reference to it?

     `let currentRecord = ClipManager()`

and... Why do I need to declare the name of the second parameter I am passing, but not the first?